# Logging wildcard query in bind

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, wildcard

I had setup a wildcard in my zone, and now I regret.
I want to found out which name is actually in use.

Any ways to log all queries that matches the wildcard in bind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can log all queries by running these 2 commands:

```
rndc querylog
rndc trace 1
```

Logs will appear in named.run. You disable logging with

```
rndc trace 0
```

I don't think it's possible to log queries for a single entry.